# Group, get subtotal and output the final result as a table?

Tags: powershell

I have following powershell script.

```
$groups = gc $fn  | 
Select -Property @{name='G1'; expression={$_.SubString(340, 7)}},
                 @{name='G2'; expression={$_.SubString(32, 2)}},
                 @{name='V1'; expression={$_.SubString(420, 8)}},
                 @{name='V2'; expression={$_.SubString(43, 11)}} |
group G1,G2

$groups | % { 
    $g = $_.Group | ? { [float]($_.V1) -ne 0 } | measure V1 -Sum #V2???
    $_.Name, $g
}
```

However I want the result as following. How to include the sum of V2? How to generate the object list for the final result?

```
Name   SumOfV1 SumOfV2
G1, G2 3243243 2432432
.....
```

Workable example:

```
ps | select -Property @{name='g1'; expression = {$_.Name}}, 
                      #@{name='g2'; expression = {$_.Id}},
                      @{name='v1'; expression = {$_.PM}},
                      @{name='v2'; expression = {$_.WS}} |
    group g1 | % {
        [pscustomobject] @{
            Name = $_.Name
            Sum = $_.Group | Measure V1,V2 -Sum | select -ExpandProperty Sum
        }
    }
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you included a sample of the dataset you are working from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piece of cake, don't even need to see your data to be honest. In your ForEach loop simply create a PSCustomObject to output down the pipe with 3 properties, the Name of the group, the sum of V1, and the sum of V2. It can be done as such:

```
$groups = gc $fn  | 
Select -Property @{name='G1'; expression={$_.SubString(340, 7)}},
                 @{name='G2'; expression={$_.SubString(32, 2)}},
                 @{name='V1'; expression={$_.SubString(420, 8)}},
                 @{name='V2'; expression={$_.SubString(43, 11)}} |
group G1,G2


$groups|ForEach{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Name'=$_.name
        'V1Sum'=$_.group|measure V1 -sum|select -expand sum
        'V2Sum'=$_.group|measure V2 -sum|select -expand sum
    }
}
```

I fabricated data for testing (yay get-random!):

```
G1     G2    V1 V2
--     --    -- --
Happy  Meals 97 20
Happy  Meals 71 21
Happy  Meals 24 54
Tickle Fight 87 19
Tickle Fight 14 18
Tickle Fight 25  0
Tickle Fight 78 51
```

This provided the output of:

```
Name          V1Sum V2Sum
----          ----- -----
Happy, Meals    192    95
Tickle, Fight   204    88
```

Comment: Can `[pscustomobject]` be omitted? Also is it possible to aggregate the Sums in one shot so it will be more efficient?

Comment: You can use `New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Name'...}` instead of [PSCustomObject] if you have an older version of PowerShell, or you can pipe to Select and create sub expressions like you did before. Or you can assign two variables similarly to how you did `$g=`, and output similarly to what you were doing. This was just the cleanest way to do it that I knew of, and provided you with objects that could be easily manipulated later if needed.

Comment: The script will be used on some huge files so I was trying to make it run as fast as possible.